# How to block incoming ports using group policy in active directory windows server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

We have a domain, and there are some computers in this domain. we applied some many policies like password policy and etc to this domain which makes it easier for us to control the use PC in our organization. Now I wonder if it is possible to stipulate a certain configuration for every PC's firewall in our domain or to force every PC in domain at least block some certain Ports and maybe IPs. Can any one help me? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible to create a policy ruling incoming connection attempts with a GPO. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc875816.aspx) is the Microsoft documentation pages on how to do that.

Go to `Computer configuration`, `Windows Settings`, `Security settings`, `Windows Firewall with advanced security`. Right clic on `Windows Firewall with advanced security`.

On global policy, you can chose to set it up (`on`), to disable it (`off`) or to let the computer decide on its own which policy to apply (`not configured`). You prefer forcing the computer to enable it (`on` option for firewall state). Then the Inbound connections (By default, I set up inbound connections to `Block`). You can also chose logging options and exceptions for allowed inbound connections (such as `icmp` which may help for debug purpose.

For a specific port/IP address, right click on `inbound rule`, `new rule`, select `Port`, and specify options you like. Once your rule is created, right click on it, the `property`, and `Scope` to specify remote/local IP address.

**EDIT:**

`Computer configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Connections -> Windows Firewall` is legacy configuration which will only apply to XP or 2003 Server.

`Computer configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` is configuration for Windows 7 or 2008 Server and later.

Pay attention that disabling firewall in one of these places will disable firewall for both cases. Have a look [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2013/01/31/deployment-windows-firewall-and-group-policy.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the edit, that makes me delete my answer ;) ;) and learn something :)